# How to send java Jetty-Runner command output to a file

Tags: java, unix, embedded-jetty

im trying to send java command output to a file, rather than the console, im trying to run  jetty runner, this is the command im using:

```
java -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar ../lib/jetty-runner.jar --port 4000 --log manager.log ../manager.war > manager.log &
echo "$!" > manager.pid
```

How can i send the output of this command to a .log file, and also save the PID as im doing it ?

AP